# number of digits in the exponent (string formatting)

Tags: python, string-formatting

It is easy to format the base of a number in python, but the exponent displays two digits by default. However, I would like to display only on digit (i.e. without the leading zero). See this example:

```
x=1.25e-5
s=f'{x:.2e}'
```

`s` will read `'1.25e-04'`, however, I would like it to be `'1.25e-4'`.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you don't mind using external packages, this can be done using [numpy.format_float_scientific](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_scientific.html?highlight=float%20scientific#numpy.format_float_scientific)

namely you can
```
import numpy as np
np.format_float_scientific(x,exp_digits=1)
```

Comment: @AnilRadhakrishnan looks like an awesome package and this is what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using external packages, this can be done using [numpy.format_float_scientific](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_scientific.html?highlight=float%20scientific#numpy.format_float_scientific)

namely you can

```
import numpy as np
x = 1.25e-5
s = np.format_float_scientific(x,exp_digits=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
format(x).replace("E-0", "E-")
```

Actually this might be better

```
(x).ToString("0.#E+0");
```